# Issue with MonoTouch

Tags: xamarin.ios

```
    I saw your website and impressed on features present in MonoTouch. I downloaded the evaluation version and installed on my MAC book using the installation guidelines given in the web site. When I tried to open MonoDevelop application, it was not opening and it saying “Application Not Responding”. I have mentioned the steps below which I had done.
```

Step1:  Updated my MAC book OS to version 10.5.8

Step2: Downloaded Apple Iphone SDK (version 3.1.4) and installed.

Step3: Downloaded Mono for Mac OS X and installed.
           Downloaded File: MonoFrameWork_24.2.3_4.macos10.novel.x86.dmg

Step4: Downloaded MonoDevelop for OS X and installed.
            Downloaded File: MonoDevelop-MonoTouch-Preview-20090922_0.dmg

Step5: Downloaded MonoTouch SDK and installed.
           Downloaded File: monotouch_eval_1.0.3.pkg

Please give me your suggestions on how to work using Monotouch in my MAC book.

Comment: Hi

Were you able to resolve this? I am also facing this

Answer (score 2):

Start the MonoDevelop program and select "New Solution" and then select the iPhone template.

There are a handful of walk through documents like:
http://monotouch.net/Tutorials/MonoDevelop_HelloWorld

Or a complete step-by-step screencast here:

http://www.codesnack.com/blog/2009/9/20/getting-started-with-monotouch.html

Building Hello world:
http://tv.falafel.com/iphone/09-09-18/Writing_your_First_IPhone_application_in_C_using_MonoTouch.aspx